# How can I solve the problem of matrices moving below the footnotes in a page?

Tags: tables, floats

I am trying to write a payoff matrix in latex, but when I do so, the outcome that I take is the following:
[image]
As you can see, the matrix is in the end of the page, below the date and the footnotes, while it should be below the proposition that refers "Example 1.1 ...payoff matrix". Why is this so? Is there any command that could help me to give the direction that I want to the matrix?

I use the package

`\usepackage{multirow,array}`
and the code is

```
\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $Y$}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{2}*{Player $X$}  & $A$ & $(2,1)$ & $(0,0)$ \\\cline{3-4}
  & $B$ & $(0,0)$ & $(1,2)$ \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the default float position includes b but you can stop that by using `\begin{table}[tp]` (or `[htp]` if you want to include h position

Comment: But why is this in a `table` at all? do you want it to move? You could just use `tabular` without the surrounding table if it is part of the proposition text.

Comment: These types of matrices are the standard notation to present the players payoffs in game theory. This is why I need the table. However, You mean that I can do the same job without using the table command?

Comment: I meant why have you got `\begin{table}` that specifies that latex may move the content to help with page breaking. It is not directly related to having a table/matrix in the content.

Comment: well i wanted the table to be centralized. I think [htp] beside the \begin{table} command does the job

Comment: `table` does not affect the horizontal position it just affects moving (or not) the content to the top or bottom of a page but glad [htbp] worked for you.

Comment: Yes I think it answers to my question

Comment: @David Carlisle one last question. If i want to have two matrices instead of one and I want them in the same line, the one besides the other, how can I do this?

Comment: just put two tabular next to each other